# "You've reached the bandwidth limit for viewing or downloading files that aren't in Google Docs format. Please try again later."

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-file-viewer

I just got this message from google docs:

> You've reached the bandwidth limit for viewing or downloading files that aren't in Google Docs format. Please try again later.
>
> You can also try to download the original document by clicking [here](http://somelink.com).

Does this message apply to the *uploader* or the *viewer* (me)?

Comment: The language suggests it applies to the viewer/downloader (you). Most people who comment on this particular error message recommend logging out of your Google account, and trying again.

Comment: I can confirm that after logging out and back in again (I *think* it was to the same Google account, I have too many), I am back in the pink.

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs does calculate in the size of the rendered document and as kind of conceivable, they render the PDF and make it available as Google Docs document. By this, you may easily get 1 MB per page and is likely based on the following google reader limits

[Bandwidth limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The referred help article is about Gmail, not about Google Drive.